# Mongo db large number of documnets in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am using mongo db, right now I am having my data stored in mysql.
Each row is unique and i want to shift the data in mongodb,

**so should i create separate document for each row or embed it in a array in chunks of 1000 per document ? **

The operations which i have to do frequently are

1) Update a specific field on a condition based on the unique id i have created 
2) Delete it after a regular interval of time.

if need any more clarification on this please let me know

Comment: Do some testing with your data and your application, on your hardware. It depends on how you want to use the data (caching, frequency of reads vs. writes, etc.). Why switch from MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can do those operations on both models, but I really don't see why embed rows in a array. If each row is unique and represents an unique entry in your data model, there is no motivation to embed it in a array.

Embed arrays/objects are often used to store data that were on distinct tables, forcing to use a JOIN on each read operation. The classic example is tags entries on a blog post: theres is a `posts` table, a `tags` table and a relationship table called `post_tags`. In a document fashion, you just embed tags on post document.

Create a separated document for each row. It will save you deal with array index operations.